# Windows 11 issue

Tags: iso-image

I have downloaded the official Windows 11 ISO from Microsoft and burned it with Rufus, but when I tried to install it on my second PC, a shortcut virus appeared and removed these 3 files (Autorun, Bootmgr, Bootmgr.efi).
I tried all the recovery file softwares but they didn't work, Is there any way to download those three files without downloading the ISO once again?

Comment: Sounds like you got tricked into installing something that wasn’t actually Windows 11.  You will have to provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

The only Windows 11 upgrade is from a Windows 10 system. That is the licensing you need.

Also Windows 11 is not "official" - just pre-release.

Join the Windows Insider Program (A setting in Windows Update and then pick your channel and install Windows 11.

Also remember that Windows 11 will download that big file about once a month. Probably one more download until October release.

I have it running here.

Answer (score 0):

When you burn an ISO directly (i.e. to an optical disc), no "shortcut virus" can possibly appear. When you use Rufus to put the installation files from the ISO onto an USB pen drive, make sure to disable anything that could interfere with it, including anti-virus software. I personally would not mind Windows Defender, but I had it interfere once before, so maybe this could also be worth trying.

When you download an ISO it seems good practice to keep it until the reason for downloading it no longer exists, meaning: use the ISO to create an installation pen drive, but don't get rid of the ISO just yet until you've successfully installed the operating system...